# get latest file on github via script

Tags: shell-script, shell, sed, scripting, wget

I am trying to do the same for https://github.com/eneshecan/whatsapp-for-linux/releases as is described here: [Download and install latest deb package from github via terminal](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7641/download-and-install-latest-deb-package-from-github-via-terminal)
but cant get it to work, it seems because the URL is not in the source but only seen in the browser?
can anyone help?
I just need the full URL as a string so I can download and install the deb file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this (kudos to [this](https://gist.github.com/lukechilds/a83e1d7127b78fef38c2914c4ececc3c) for the trick that gets the latest version):

```
base_url="https://github.com/eneshecan/whatsapp-for-linux/releases/download"
version=$(curl --silent https://api.github.com/repos/eneshecan/whatsapp-for-linux/releases | grep -oP '"tag_name":\s*"v\K[^"]+' | sort -h | tail -n1)
wget "$base_url"/v"$version"/whatsapp-for-linux_"${version}"_amd64.deb
```

Comment: thanks, different solution :-)
I wonder why its so complicated on some github repos

I marked it as solution as it works for my use-case :-)

Comment: @Questi it's because there is no standard here, and every developer can arrange their repository as they want.

Answer (score 1):

I use the following to choose (using bash's `select` built-in) one or more of the most recent "Glorious Eggroll" Proton releases to download and extract for Steam.

It would be easy enough to modify to download a .deb file from another repo.  It does basically the same thing as @terdon's answer, but a bit fancier (the `select` stuff; and code to avoid downloading a file that has already been downloaded, checking both the current dir and a `./archives/` sub-directory - I like to move older .tar.gz files out of the main working dir to reduce clutter; and code to extract the download if it hasn't already been extracted into the target dir).

```bash
#!/bin/bash

GE_API_URL='https://api.github.com/repos/GloriousEggroll/proton-ge-custom/releases'
GE_json='GE-releases.json'
GE_list='GE-releases.list'
compatdir='/var/games/steam/compatibilitytools.d'
archives='./archives'

mkdir -p "$compatdir"

# Don't download the releases file more than once/day
if [ -e "$GE_json" ] ; then
  GE_date="$(stat --printf "%y" "$GE_json" | cut -d' ' -f 1)"
fi
YMD="$(date +%Y-%m-%d)"

if [ "$GE_date" != "$YMD" ] ; then
  wget "$GE_API_URL" -O "$GE_json"
  jq -r .[].assets[].browser_download_url < "$GE_json" |
    grep '\.tar.gz$' | sort -rV > "$GE_list"
fi

#mapfile -t releases < "$GE_list"         # all
mapfile -t releases < <(head "$GE_list")  # latest 10

echo "Currently installed Proton-GE versions:"
ls "$compatdir" | grep GE | sort -rV
echo

export COLUMNS=80
echo "Select a GE release to download and install or 0 to quit:"
select r in "${releases[@]}"; do
  [ -z "$r" ] && break

  tgz="$(basename "$r")"
  [ -e "$archives/$tgz" ] && tgz="$archives/$tgz"
  if [ ! -e "$tgz" ] ; then
     echo "Downloading $r"
     wget "$r"
  fi

  bn="$(basename "$tgz" ".tar.gz")"
  if [ ! -e "$compatdir/$bn" ] ; then
    echo "Extracting $bn into $compatdir/"
    time tar xfz "$tgz" -C "$compatdir/"
  fi

  echo
  echo -n "Select another version to install or 0 to quit: "
done
```

Comment: not sure how to use this :P
though it would be nice to check if there is already a downloaded file and if its the newest version to not attempt to download and install it :)